# Как Powershell всегда открывать с флагом -NoLogo

Tags: windows, powershell

Задача: я хочу, чтобы Powershell открывался всегда с флагом -NoLogo

Чтобы, если я в vscode открыл терминал и в нём открыл Powershell, то не было стартовых логов, и также, чтобы при простом открытии Powershell в нём не появлялись логи.
Не знаю как это сделать, подскажите

Comment: А этот ответ [ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262269/) подходит?

Comment: @Daemon-5 да, как раз, мне помог этот ответ https://stackoverflow.com/a/59954137/12300532

Comment: Правда, я сделал просто так, чтобы при старте Powershell появляется этот текст и через несколько миллисекунд пропадает лог и срабатывает команда clear.

Answer (score -1):

```
powershell.exe -NoLogo
```

думаю вот так должно получиться главное мимо клавиш не промахиваться

Comment: Мне надо, чтобы в моей операционной системе при запуске powershell без флагов не появились сообщения

Comment: Мне помог этот ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59954137/12300532